# Error evaluating arithmetic expression

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I am an Erlang beginner and am trying to make a simple command-line application where the user enters the width and height of a floor, the cost per square foot of flooring and they are returned a price. Essentially I'm just accepting three integer values and returning the product.

```
23> c(costcalc).
{ok,costcalc}
24> costcalc:start().
Calculate the cost of flooring based on width, height, and cost per square foot.

Width in feet: 5
Height in feet: 5
Cost in dollars per square foot: $4
** exception error: an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression in function  costcalc:start/0 (costcalc.erl, line 23)
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
start() ->
  io:format("Calculate the cost of flooring based on width, height, and cost per square foot.\n"),
  W = string:to_integer(io:get_line("Width in feet: ")),
  H = string:to_integer(io:get_line("Height in feet: ")),
  C = string:to_integer(io:get_line("Cost in dollars per square foot: $")),
  Cost = W * H * C,
  io:fwrite(Cost).
```

Line 23 is `Cost = W * H * C,` which should be 100. When I run `5 * 5 * 4.` in the shell directly it calculates without issue. I should also note that this happens whether or not I use string:to_integer() which I would imagine I can get by without.

What am I missing?

Comment: I added the problem with io! you are missing the format ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Khashayar, the problem in your code is that [`string:to_integer/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#to_integer-1) returns a pair (a tuple with two elements) and the integer is the first element.

However, **you should not use this function**. A string in Erlang is just a list of integers, and what you meant to use is [`list_to_integer/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_integer-1). This is the common way to convert a string to an integer.

If you used [`list_to_integer/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_integer-1), you would have avoided the bug in @Khashayar's code where the second pair element is matched with anything. Indeed, you can enter the following:

```
Calculate the cost of flooring based on width, height, and cost per square foot. 
Width in feet: 1.9
Height in feet: 1.9
Cost in dollars per square foot: $ 4.9
4
```

While `1.9*1.9*4.9` actually equals `17.689`.

Unfortunately, there is no `list_to_number/1` function which would return either an integer or a float. The most common way to handle this is to perform a try/catch with `list_to_float/1` and fallback to `list_to_integer/1`. Alternatively, you could use [`io_lib:fread/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#fread-2) or [`string:to_float/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_float-1) which do not raise exceptions (still, as mentioned above, using [`string:to_float/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_float-1) is judged a bad practice).

Comment: I can't test the code for several more hours, but if one uses `list_to_float/1` and an integer is returned does it cause an exception or will it be 1.0, 2.0, etc?

Comment: `list_to_float/1` will definitely raise a badarg error when passed a string representation of an integer (e.g. `"1"`). This is [documented](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_float-1).

Answer (score 1):

the problem you have is with string:to_integer, it returns 2 values! you should use them like this.

```
start() ->
    io:format("Calculate the cost of flooring based on width, height, and cost per square foot.\n"),
    {W,_} = string:to_integer(io:get_line("Width in feet: ")),
    {H,_} = string:to_integer(io:get_line("Height in feet: ")),
    {C,_} = string:to_integer(io:get_line("Cost in dollars per square foot: $ ")),
    Cost = (W * H) * C,
    io:fwrite("~p~n",[Cost]).
```

The second value is the rest of the string by the way,

to_integer(String) -> {Int, Rest} | {error, Reason}

good luck